# The pattern - be +adjective+ as + to verb

Tags: construction

All these sentences have this pattern "be +adjective+ as + to verb"

**I was told that these are correct:**

> 1 How could you *be so stupid as to think* that would work?
>
> 2 My headache *was not so bad as to prevent* me from going to the party.
>
> 3 The box *was so heavy as to be* impossible to lift.
>
> 4 This problem *is so easy as to be* solved by a five-year-old.

**But this one is wrong**

> 5 He *was so strong as to lift* that box.

**Do you agree it's wrong? If yes, what makes it wrong?**

Comment: I don't find (4) particularly natural - I would say _so easy, it could be solved by a five-year-old_ or _easy enough to be..._. I think _He was so strong as to be able to lift that box_ is possible, but sounds old-fashioned. Most people would say _He was strong enough to..._

Comment: Why does 5 stand out? It has the same pattern.

Comment: Another common expression is "so adjective that". I think all your sentences are correct.

Comment: @Man_From_India If your username is literal, I wonder whether it's a dialectal thing? I'm Australian and I concur with Kate: 1-3 fine, 4 weird, 5 definitely wrong.

Comment: @TimPederick yes I am Indian, and a non native. So I believe if it is popular in a non native place, that doesn't mean it is correct. May be it is dialectical, but I would still think that it is wrong use of a foreign language. But you see I really didn't like those sentences, I was more comfortable with "so adjective that" structure. But when I made that comment I searched AmeE corpus, and found that this construction is nothing new.

Comment: "Many believe that tattoos have become so widespread as to be considered mainstream". This one is one example. Oh Kare didn't find #5 actually wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the first three of your examples are good English, and the other two are not. This works fine for the explanation of why the bad ones don't work.

The structure **[ "so" + *adjective* + "as to" + *base form* ]** has the same meaning as **[ "so" + *adjective* + "that" + *noun* + *simple past* ]**, like this:

> 1 How could you be so stupid **that you thought** that would work?
> 2 My headache was not so bad **that it prevented** me from going to the party.
> 3 The box was so heavy **that it was** impossible to lift.

These new sentences all make perfect sense.

But when we apply the same transformation to the other two sentences, we get these new ones:

> 4 This problem is so easy **that it was** solved by a five-year-old.
> 5 He was so strong **that he lifted** that box.

You can get the feeling of what's intended, but the meaning isn't good. Those sentences should read something like:

> "... that it **was solvable** by a five-year-old"
> "... that he **was able** to lift that box."

So with the "so ... as to" structure, they should read:

> "This problem is so easy as to be **solvable** by a five-year-old."
> "He was so strong as to **be able** to lift that box.

Comment: Good answer that makes me want to dive deeper on *why* the transformed sentences aren't good. Looking at sentence 3, I too thought thought that it needed to be changed to "solvable", not "solved". I wonder whether this means that the difference is *semantic*? That "so X as to Y" properly describes a state Y, not an action? Just speculating, I haven't pondered (counter-)arguments or anything.

Comment: Here is an example from a book by Sarah Brady, ‎Merrill Mcloughlin. She grabbed his arm , but Jim was so strong that he lifted her right up and she went flying across the bed

Comment: Gotube, I feel being at odds with this "My headache was not so bad that it prevented me from going to the party." Shouldn't it be "My headache was not so bad that it didn't prevent me from going to the party."

Comment: @user1425 No. Your first sentence means you were able to go to the party with a headache. The phrase, "*so bad that it prevented me from going to the party*" is an adjective phrase describing the headache. Was it that bad? No. So just one "not" will do